# Mapreduce - Right way to confirm whether the file is split or not

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

We had a lot of xml files and we wanted to process one xml using one mapper task because of obvious reasons to make the processing ( parsing ) simpler.

We wrote a mapreduce program to achieve that by overriding isSplitable method of input format class.It seems it is working fine.

However, we wanted to confirm if one mapper is used to process one xml file. IS there is a way to confirm by looking at the logs produced by driver program or any other way .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Just check the number of mapper count.
It should be equal to your number of input files.

Example :

```
/ds/input 
    /file1.xml
    /file2.xml
    /file3.xml
```

Then the mapper count should be 3.

Comment: Thanks Back, is it true even if there is only one mapper ?

Comment: Yes. If there is only one input split is created by your `InputFormat` class, there will be only one mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command.

```
 mapred job -counter job_1449114544347_0001 org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter TOTAL_LAUNCHED_MAPS
```

You can get many details using mapred job -counter command. You can check video 54 and 55 from this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8p7ZYBB5DmRHK3L6aq8Mvcv). It covers counters in detail.